# Fine Uploader chunking in Safari?

Tags: android, safari, fine-uploader

I am using Fine Uploader + jQuery and PHP and everything works fine in Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera... etc. But i tested it on Safari and on several android phones and it does not split the files into chunks. Fine uploader is sending the whole file. What am i missing? I readed the whole documentation (i think so) and there i did not found anything related about iOS/Android/Safari.

This is the $_POST send by Chrome

```
[uniqueid] => 75743724051801b4b497c5
[qqpartindex] => 0
[qqpartbyteoffset] => 0
[qqchunksize] => 65535
[qqtotalparts] => 69
[qqtotalfilesize] => 4475550
[qqfilename] => DSCF1803.JPG
[qquuid] => 573dba70-6b45-4ea4-95a5-07597d37ed80
```

and from Safari

```
[qquuid] => a66e27f4-769a-46d8-8429-b0d975a519e1
[qqtotalfilesize] => 4475550
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chunking is not supported on Android due to an Android-related bug.  I discuss this in [my blog post on the chunking feature](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2012/12/file-chunkingpartitioning-is-now.html).  What version of Safari are you using, and which OS?

Comment: I'm using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 8. If is not suported on Android, how can i upload bigger files with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari on OSX is supported, but Safari on Windows is definitely not supported.  There is no good reason to use Safari on Windows.  Safari was created for Windows to bring a WebKit browser to the PC.  That need is much better fulfilled with Chrome.  In fact, Apple doesn't appear to be interested in supporting or contributing further development to Safari on Windows either.  Use Chrome on Windows, not Safari.

As far as chunking on Android is concerned, I've explained why this is not currently possible.  This certainly doesn't stop you from uploading "large" files from an Android, but what sort of "large" files would you be uploading from an Android anyway.

Comment: By large files i mean .mp3 files, not so big. But i don't want to reload the page. Is there a way to upload without page refresh? I'm not so good with js/ajax stuff.

I was just testing some browsers, i dont realy need Safari Windows support.

Comment: No page reload occurs for any uploads when using Fine Uploader.  I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, but.. when i upload files via IE/Chrome etc. the file is sended chunked via $_POST. When i try to upload it via Android the file is sended whole (not splited on parts) and i get "HTTP Error 413 Request entity too large". What can i do about this? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a server-side issue.  You'll need to adjust your server to handle larger requests it seems.  Chunking/splitting is not currently possible in Android.